# d3 add line to chart, issue with cover line

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 to draw a chart, But I need to add middle line manually.
I use the lib's axis to translate a 'g' to draw the middle line, but the lines for y-axis 'cut' the vertical red line as the below, so can it set css like 'z-index' to above the line?

[image]

Comment: There is not `z-index` in SVG, the elements are rendered in the order in which they are appended. For an element to appear on top, it should be appended last or be a child of the container element appended last.

Comment: you might want to look at d3 insert instead of append to accomplish this.  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#insert